# Can't generate query files for apollo-graphql client

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo-client

I'm trying to follow [Apollo graphql tutorial](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/introduction/) and stuck at creating [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/tutorial/client/)
When I run `npm run codegen` which is translated to `apollo client:codegen --target typescript --watch` it gives me the following error:

```
Generating query files with 'typescript' target
    → Syntax error in file:///Users/anatoly/Documents/git/fullstack-tutorial/start/client/src/pages/launches.tsx: Syntax Error: Unexpected <
…
```

My *launches.tsx* looks correct:

```
import React, { Fragment }  from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from '@reach/router';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

interface LaunchesProps extends RouteComponentProps {}

const Launches: React.FC<LaunchesProps> = () => {
  return <div />;
}

export const LAUNCH_TILE_DATA = gql`
`;

export default Launches;
```

My *package.json* is following:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "3.0.0",
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.14",
    "@types/reach__router": "^1.2.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.6.2",
    "apollo-client": "^2.6.10",
    "apollo-link-http": "^1.5.15",
    "emotion": "^9.2.12",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.10.1",
    "polished": "^3.4.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0-alpha.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0-alpha.0",
    "react-emotion": "^9.2.12",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "run:ios-demo": "npx artillery run apollo-internal-demos/ios-workload.yml",
    "codegen": "apollo client:codegen --target typescript --watch"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-testing": "3.0.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^8.0.7",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "apollo": "^2.28.3",
    "artillery": "^1.6.0-26",
    "npm-watch": "^0.6.0"
  }
}
```

Tried with node v14.4.0 and v13.12.0, same error. Any suggestions what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Add query to `LAUNCH_TILE_DATA` maybe?

Comment: I don't sure, it's my first steps with GraphQL and it isn't covered by the tutorial so I haven't added any. Will try to play with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try command
`npx apollo-codegen introspect-schema http://localhost:4000/graphql --output ./types/schema.json`
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I will still comment even if this is late. I solved this problem by downloading the graphql schema again
`npx apollo schema:download --endpoint=my_endpoint ./src/app/graphql/graphql.schema.json` before going back to generate the schema